# Ajax通信処理完了後にフォームからPOST送信したい／1クリックで

Tags: javascript

**やりたいこと**
1.フォーム送信ボタンクリック
2.AjaxのGET通信でデータ取得し、フォームへセット
3.フォーム機能を使用してPOST送信

**現状**
1.Ajax用のボタンクリック
2.AjaxのGET通信でデータ取得し、フォームへセット
3.フォームの送信ボタンクリック
4.フォーム機能を使用してPOST送信

**質問**
・Ajax通信処理完了を待って、(新たにボタンクリックすることなく)フォームからPOST送信することは可能？
・Ajax通信処理完了を待つためには、フォーム送信するのではなく、Ajax処理後にさらにAjax処理でPOST通信するしかない？

**その他**
・フォームからPOST送信したいのは、既存で実現できるから
・Ajax処理後にさらにAjax処理で、フォームデータを全てPOST通信するのは、難しそうな気がするので回避する方法がないか質問しました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jqueryを使っている事を前提ですと、

```
$.ajax({url:"...",type:"GET"}).done(function(data){
    //formにデータを入れる処理

    $("#myform").submit();
})
```

でできるかと思います。 ただ formにデータをいれる所までできているようなら、

```
$.ajax({url:"...",type:"POST",data:$("#myform").serialize()})
```

で簡単にpost送信できるかと思います。